# How to deploy an eureka naming server on aks?

Tags: yaml, netflix-eureka, azure-aks

I want to deploy my web service to Azure Kubernetes Service. I currently have 3 microservices in one node. 1 API gateway and 2 backend microservices. Error messages: none. Because I do not use routes in the API gateway, I cannot control my backend microservice via the API gateway. Now I have created a Eureka Naming Server, and want to deloy him in the same node, that I want to use so that my microservices can communicate with each other.

This is my Yaml-File that i used for the Naming Server

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: discoeryservice-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: discoveryservice-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: discoveryservice-front
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: discoveryservice-front
          image: registry.azurecr.io/discoveryservice:16
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 512Mi
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8762
            name: discovery

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: discoveryservice-front
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8762
  selector:
    app: discoveryservice-front


---
```

First of all I don't get an external IP address and I don't know why. Can someone tell me how to get an external IP for my naming server?

This is my Yaml-File for the rest of microservices

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apigateway-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apigateway-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apigateway-front
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: apigateway-front
          image: registry.azurecr.io/apigateway:11
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 512Mi
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8800
            name: apigateway

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apigateway-front
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8800
  selector:
    app: apigateway-front


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: contacts-back
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: contacts-back
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: contacts-back
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: contacts-back
        image: registry.azurecr.io/contacts:12
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 512Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8100
          name: contacts-back

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: contacts-back
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8100
  selector:
    app: contacts-back
---


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: templates-back
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: templates-back
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: templates-back
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: templates-back
        image: registry.azurecr.io/templates:13
        resources:
         requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
         limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 512Mi
        ports:
         - containerPort: 8200
           name: templates-back
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: templates-back
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8200
  selector:
    app: templates-back
```

Secondly. Can someone tell me how I register my microservices with the naming server?
If I start my microservice without AKS and without Docker then the naming server works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using kubernetes, the suggested approach would be to use k8s service discovery instead of eureka service discovery. 
For API Gateway, you can use any k8s native api gateways like ambassador and kong which integrate very well with kubernetes.

To answer above questions

1. External IP is provided to services which are of type load balancer (I am assuming by external ip you meant IP address which can be used from outside of cluster).
2. To register to eureka service discovery, I guess you will need to make minor changes in the code (to inform eureka once the application is up in order to register it's instance).

If there is some doubt in above answers, please comment, will try to explain in depth too.

Comment: Ok thanks for ur answer. Step 1 works for me. But with 2 I'm not really sure what to do.  I guess I have to set a route to my naming service in the yaml file of my microservices right?

Comment: For second part, it would depend on how your microservices are built? If you are using some framework like spring framework, you can follow specific guide to enable eureka service discovery (e.g. https://piotrminkowski.com/2018/04/26/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-spring-boot-2-0-eureka-and-spring-cloud/). 

This would require change in code and only yaml won't be able to help in service discovery using eureka. However if you use cloud native api gateway, you can use yaml services for service discovery.

Comment: If I run my microservices on my computer, the naming service works. Yes I use Spring Boot and everything works fine. However, when I provide my microservices, my services are not registered.

Comment: In AKS, have you provided the information of service registry to your spring boot application (in application.properties file). By information, I mean address of eureka service so that it can register itself with eureka.
Locally, since both are running locally, it migt be able to identify easily.